# Bash: Backup script runs on shell exit

Tags: bash, backup

I have developed a menu in bash with some options(only backup will be included here), one of these options is to backup, however whenever I close the shell, the backup command runs and makes a backup by it self.

I tried adding break and exit before ;; but it just stops the whole script.

```
#!/bin/bash

menu=$(echo "Choose operation [1]Hi [2]Backup")

echo "$menu"

while [ $# == 0 ]; do
  read options

  case "$options" in
    1 )  
    echo "HI"  
    echo "$menu"
  ;;

  2 )
    dir="/home/backups"
    bckup="$(date +%d%b%Y_%H%M)"
    mkdir $dir/$bckup
    cat /etc/passwd >> $dir/$bckup/"DB$bckup".txt

    dialog --title "DATABASE" --msgbox " Ready to backup user database. \n
    press <Enter> to start or <Esc> to cancel." 10 50

    # Return status of non-zero indicates cancel
    if [ "$?" != "0" ]
    then
        dialog --title "BACKUP" --msgbox " Backup was canceled at your request." 10 50
    else
        dialog --title "BACKUP" --infobox " Backup in process..." 10 50 ; sleep 1

        tar czf $dir/$bckup.tgz -C $dir/$bckup . >|/tmp/ERRORS$$ 2>&1

      # zero status indicates backup was successful
      if [ "$?" = "0" ]
      then
        dialog --title "BACKUP" --msgbox " Backup completed successfully." 10 50
      else
        dialog --title "BACKUP" --msgbox "Backup failed Press <Enter> to see error log." 10 50
       dialog --title "Error Log" --textbox /tmp/ERRORS$$ 22 72
      fi
    fi
    rm -r -f $dir/$bckup
    rm -f /tmp/ERRORS$$
    clear
    echo "$menu"
  ;;

  *)
    echo "Invalid, Please choose a valid option"
  ;;
esac
done
exit
```

Comment: Your menu should run a script that does that backup - so you can test the backup in isolation.  It would also make the code easier to understand; the erratic indentation shown doesn't help its legibility in the least.  (Tabs are not recommended in code presented at SO.)

Comment: use the shell debugging feature, i.e. `set -vx` near the top of the script. It will print out each line/block as it is evaluated by the script AND it will show the values of the variables. You should be able to see why it is running the backup. (Not obvious here). Good luck.

Comment: Hi, I will make the script run that backup in isolation if there is no other option then, thanks.

Comment: As a comment on style, `menu=$(echo "text")` is more elegantly expressed as `menu="text"`.  The echo in backticks is a common newbie antipattern.

Comment: Please do not delete the script.  It makes it hard for people coming later to understand what the comments and answers are talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens when you type EOF to:

```
read options
```

You don't test whether that worked.  It is likely that `options` contains the previous value, and that you previously tried backup.  If the diagnosis is correct, then the fix is pretty simple:

```
if read options
then
    ...the script you currently have interpreting $options
else break  # The while loop ... which has an interesting (read 'unusual') condition.
fi
```

You could (should?) provide an explicit exit option too, but this should protect you from unexpected backups after you type <kbd>Control-D</kbd> or whatever it is you use as an EOF indication to the terminal.

A slightly more radical reorganization uses:

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    while read options
    do
        ...the script you currently have interpreting $options
    done
fi
```

or:

```
if [ $# -ne 0 ]
then exit 1
fi

while read options
do
    ...the script you currently have interpreting $options
done
```

---

> Please tell me what's the difference between `while [ $# == 0 ];` and `[ $# -ne 0 ]` and `-eq`.

It is a question of shell semantics.

- `while [ $# == 0 ]` does a string equality comparison of the number of arguments `$#` against `0`.
- `while [ $# != 0 ]` does a string inequality comparison of the number of arguments and 0.
- `while [ $# -ne 0 ]` does a numeric inequality comparison of the number of arguments and 0.
- `while [ $# -eq 0 ]` does a numeric equality comparison of the number of arguments and 0.

Note that this is the converse of the Perl convention, where:

- `$x == 0` is numeric equality
- `$x != 0` is numeric inequality
- `$x eq 0` is string equality
- `$x ne 0` is string inequality

In all pairs of cases, the result is the same when the comparisons are (in)equality and the values are expressed conventionally (using the minimum number of digits and expressed as an integer).  The numeric versus string comparison matters for ordering comparisons (`>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=`).

Your original code loops on `while [ $# == 0 ]` (while there are no positional arguments).  If there are any arguments (so `$# != 0` or `$# > 0`, since the number of arguments is never negative), the loop is never entered.

The first of my rewrites checks that there are no arguments before entering the `while read options` loop.

The second of my rewrites exits early if there are any arguments and so does not enter the `while read options` loop at all when arguments are present.  They are equivalent except that the first rewrite has the body of the loop nested one level more deeply.

Note that none of the code shown ever changes the number of positional parameters (number of arguments).  You'd do that with `set -- arg1 arg2 ...` if you really wanted to, but you probably don't.

Comment: This makes sense, but im a bit lost i just started scripting 3 days ago, should i use EOF,HERE or STOP tags

Comment: Yes i did make a backup to test if it works cause i just changed some of the code, then i exit the shell and then i find a new backup in the folder meaning that the command runned by its self

Comment: How would i add EOF to read? something like read options <<EOF 
i dont know what eof is for

Comment: As I show in the edited version of the answer, testing the status of `read`.  The '<<EOF' notation is for a 'here document', where the text of the input document is contained in the lines following the redirection, up to the line containing just 'EOF' as a word.

Comment: I've chosen the second option and it fixed the issue. I need to understand each line of code, please tell me whats the difference between while [ $# == 0 ];  and [ $# -ne 0 ] and -eq